# How to call stored procedure in EF4

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in Entity Framework 4 application and so far getting strange results. Stored procedure takes `IN` and `OUT` parameters, and returns resultset. I mapped stored procedure and created a complex type that represents a row in returned resultset. I call it

```
using (MyObjectContext ctx = new MyObjectContext())
{
     ObjectParameter out1 = new ObjectParameter("out1", typeof(String));
     ObjectParameter out2 = new ObjectParameter("out2", typeof(String));     
     var res = ctx.my_proc(1,2, out1,out2);
}
```

The problem is that unless I call `res.ToList()` (or enumerate through `res`, or call any methods that accesses underlying collection), values of `out1` and `out2` are `null`.
How do I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: In this case I would expect procedure not to be executed until I call `ToList()`.  But in fact it runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot fix it. It is a gotcha. Result set must be materialized or thrown away before output parameters are accessible because these output parameters are transferred in the last result set so internal data reader must first read the returning result set with main data and then access the next result set to read output parameters. Btw. it is the same if you use ADO.NET directly - that is not a feature of Entity framework itself but the way how SQL server returns output parameters and the way how DataReader consumes result sets in sequential order.

Comment: Thanks; anyway I need to get results and iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

when u call procedure or query that returns a table of rows
EF does real execution when user calls ToList or enumerate the return value